# python json, replacing values with key and value pairs

Tags: python, json

in the following example I am trying to replace value of one key by the value of another key; but I tried multiple ways and it doesn't seem to work.

following is my code

```
d = {
  "name" : "ABC",
  "type" : "Service",
  "clusterRef" : {
    "clusterName" : "ABCSTUFF"
  },
  "serviceState" : "STARTED",
  "healthChecks" : [ {
    "name" : "STORAGE",
    "summary" : "GOOD"
  }, {
    "name" : "CPU UTILIZATION",
    "summary" : "GOOD"
  } ],
  "maintenanceMode" : "false"
}


########################
## Get Key Value

def get_key_values(d, key):
  for k, v in d.items():
    if k == "name":
        k = (key + "." + v)
    else:
        k = (key + "." + k)
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        get_key_values(v, k)
    elif isinstance(v, list):
        for i in v:
            get_key_values(i, k)
    else:
        print ("{0} : {1}".format(k, v))


get_key_values(d, "TTS")
```

the result come up like following

> ```
> TTS.serviceState : STARTED 
> TTS.type : Service 
> TTS.ABC : ABC
> TTS.clusterRef.clusterName : ABCSTUFF
> TTS.healthChecks.summary : GOOD         <<< remove this line and replace "Good" with  the value for "TTS.healthChecks.STORAGE"
> TTS.healthChecks.STORAGE : STORAGE
> TTS.healthChecks.summary : GOOD         <<< remove this line and replace "Good" with  the value for "TTS.healthChecks.CPU UTILIZATION"
> TTS.healthChecks.CPU UTILIZATION : CPU UTILIZATION
> TTS.maintenanceMode : false
> ```

but I want the result to be following

> ```
> TTS.serviceState : STARTED 
> TTS.type : Service 
> TTS.ABC : ABC
> TTS.clusterRef.clusterName : ABCSTUFF
> TTS.healthChecks.STORAGE : GOOD                 <<<
> TTS.healthChecks.CPU UTILIZATION : GOOD         <<<
> TTS.maintenanceMode : false
> ```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Are you able to restructure the data, or do you have to work with the data in that exact format?

Comment: nope, can't restructure the data, as its being fetched from and external API

Comment: Have you tried using the `json` library and modifying the dictionary you get from loading your json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a non-generic solution which works for your question:

```
d = {
    "name": "ABC",
    "type": "Service",
    "clusterRef": {
        "clusterName": "ABCSTUFF"
    },
    "serviceState": "STARTED",
    "healthChecks": [{
        "name": "STORAGE",
        "summary": "GOOD"
    }, {
        "name": "CPU UTILIZATION",
        "summary": "GOOD"
    }],
    "maintenanceMode": "false"
}


########################
# Get Key Value

def get_key_values(d, key):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k == "name":
            k = (key + "." + v)
        else:
            k = (key + "." + k)

        if isinstance(v, dict):
            get_key_values(v, k)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for i in v:
                tok1 = k + "." + i.get("name")
                tok2 = i.get("summary")
                print("{0} : {1}".format(tok1, tok2))
        else:
            print("{0} : {1}".format(k, v))

get_key_values(d, "TTS")
```